# Calculating scores using user input

Tags: java

I need to be able to complete this program.  I am completely lost after missing a class.  I need to be able to out put to a txt file the Total, Percentage, Highest, Lowest and Grade.  I have it where I can input the 5 scores given to me but the rest is not working.  I am completely lost, no idea where I need to go from what I have.  I can use a loop but its not necessary.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BenefieldProgram4 {

 public static void main(String[ ] args)  {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter 5 Grades:");
         System.out.println("");
         keyboard.nextDouble();
         double a, b, c, d, e; //5 Grades
         double sum = 0;     // total
         double avg;        // percentage
         double min = 1;    // lowest grade
         double max = 100;  // highest grade

         //Calculations
         a = keyboard.nextDouble();
         b = keyboard.nextDouble();
         c = keyboard.nextDouble();
         d = keyboard.nextDouble();
         e = keyboard.nextDouble();
         keyboard.close();

         sum = (a+b+c+d+e);
         System.out.println("Total Score=:"+sum);

         avg =(a+b+c+d+e)/500;
         System.out.println("Percentage =: "+avg); 

         max = Double.MAX_VALUE;  
         System.out.println("Highest Score= " +max);

         min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
         System.out.println("Lowest Score= " +min);

         if (avg >= 90)
            System.out.println("Grade= A");
            else if (avg >=80)
            System.out.println("Grade= B");
            else if (avg >= 70)
            System.out.println("Grade= C");
            else if (avg >= 60)
            System.out.println("Grade= D");
            else
            System.out.println("Grade= F");
             }
 }
}
```

*Edit*

Comment: ok, so all you have to do now is write to a file?

Comment: Could you re-format your code? Select it and press CTRL+K. Could you fix the indenting on your `if`-`else if` block? I was going to edit your post but I didn't want to accidentally add something that wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: So now you just need to write to a text file? But i also see that you have `6 keyboard.nextDouble()` when you say you only want to read in `5` grades

Comment: by the way, what do you mean by "the rest is not working" ? also how many times do you have to calculate the avg and the other stuff? is it just once for the five grades you are reading?

Comment: Pressing CTRL+K did nothing for the formatting but I did it anyways. Constants a-e are only 5, not sure where the 6th one is that you are referring too.  Once I input the 5 scores given and hit return it should calculate each Total, Percentage, etc and it does nothing.  As for the indent in the if else statements that how the program writes them but if I need to fix them for you a certain way just tell me how you would like them. The results from each one needs to be written to a text file but that is the last step I would like to fix what I have first.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
// The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "temp.txt";

        try {
            // Assume default encoding.
            FileWriter fileWriter =
                new FileWriter(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            // Note that write() does not automatically
            // append a newline character.
            bufferedWriter.write("Hello there,");
            bufferedWriter.write(" here is some text.");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.write("We are writing");
            bufferedWriter.write(" the text to the file.");

            // Always close files.
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error writing to file '"
                + fileName + "'");
            // Or we could just do this:
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and just write whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for ;)

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 Grades:");
    System.out.println("");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/var/tmp/test.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.newLine();

    double a, b, c, d, e; //5 Grades
    double sum = 0;     // total
    double avg;        // percentage
    double min = 1;    // lowest grade
    double max = 100;  // highest grade

    //Calculations
    a = keyboard.nextDouble();
    b = keyboard.nextDouble();
    c = keyboard.nextDouble();
    d = keyboard.nextDouble();
    e = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.close();

    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    list.add(c);
    list.add(d);
    list.add(e);
    sum = (a+b+c+d+e);
    System.out.println("Total Score=:"+sum);
    bw.append("Total Score=:"+sum);
    bw.newLine();
    avg =(a+b+c+d+e)/5;
    System.out.println("Percentage =: "+avg); 
    bw.append("Percentage =: "+avg);
    bw.newLine();
    max = Collections.max(list);  
    System.out.println("Highest Score= " +max);
    bw.append("Highest Score= " +max);
    bw.newLine();
    min = Collections.min(list);
    System.out.println("Lowest Score= " +min);
    bw.append("Lowest Score= " +min);
    bw.newLine();
    if (avg >= 90){
       System.out.println("Grade= A");
       bw.append("Grade= A");
       bw.newLine();
    }
       else if (avg >=80){
       System.out.println("Grade= B");
       bw.append("Grade= B");
       bw.newLine();
       }
       else if (avg >= 70){
       System.out.println("Grade= C");
       bw.append("Grade= C");
       bw.newLine();
       }
       else if (avg >= 60){
       System.out.println("Grade= D");
       bw.append("Grade= D");
       bw.newLine();
       }
       else {
       System.out.println("Grade= F");
       bw.append("Grade= F");
       bw.newLine();
       }
    bw.close();
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PrintWriter`.

```
try {

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println("The first line");
    writer.println("The second line");
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error writing to file");
}
```

Basically, just throw whatever you want to put into your file in a `writer.println()` statement.